# How to get X from createElement('img')

Tags: javascript, css, html

How do you get the X(left) position from the tag document.createElement('img');

```
var block00 = document.createElement("img");
block00.src = "images/sep1.png";
```

Can you use:

```
if (block00.getBoundingClientRect) {
    var doc2 = block00.getBoundingClientRect();
    var X = doc2.left;
    console.log(X);
}
```

Comment: that element has no position until it is added to the DOM

Comment: how do I capture it?

Comment: After appending it in DOM, you can get position of the element!

Comment: once the element is in the DOM, getBoundingClientRect is a good way to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

First you have to appendChild();

```
        var block02 = document.createElement("img"); // ADD SEPERATION BLOCK(BLOCK HOLE)
        block02.src = "images/sep1.png"; // ADD SEPERATION BLOCK(BLOCK HOLE)
        document.getElementById("land01").appendChild(block02); // APPEND CHILD(BLOCK HOLE)

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //
        // BLOCK02 GET X POS OF ADDED BLOCK 

        if (getX1 == 0) { //////////////////////////////////////////// SET (BLOCK HOLE) X
            var doc2 = block02.getBoundingClientRect();
            gX1 = doc2.left;
            getX1 = 1;
        }
```